# How to read data from an array containing object within him

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

Im having a hard time to read some data that i get from joomla 2.5. First i have created a module that stores data on DB as a json. So first i read from DB linke:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();


$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('params')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__modules'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('module') . ' = '. $db->quote('mod_products'));


// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

and the result that i get as an array that contain objects, and each object has json data.
below is the arrray that i get from the query:

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
  (
   [params] => {
     "product_name":"Sangiovese",
     "product_subtitle":"Maremma Toscana DOC",
     "product_category":"Red",
     "isvisible":"1"
      } 
  ) 
 [1] => stdClass Object 
  ( 
   [params] => {
    "product_name":"Syrah",
    "product_subtitle":"Maremma Toscana DOC",
    "product_category":"Red",
    "isvisible":"0",
      } 
  ) 
 [2] => stdClass Object 
  ( 
   [params] => {
    "product_name":"Merlot",
    "product_subtitle":"Maremma Toscana DOC",
    "product_category":"Red",
    "isvisible":"0"
      } 
  ) 
 [3] => stdClass Object 
  ( 
   [params] => {
    "product_name":"Vermentino",
    "product_subtitle":"Maremma Toscana DOC",
    "product_category":"White",
    "isvisible":"0"
      } 
  ) 
);
```

So what i want to do is to access the data within each param for examle:

PS: Array name is $results.
, 
EX: i want to access **product_name** of each of the products that are on this array, or subtitle and so on.

so i did something like this, but its not working, i know i am not doing it right,  but i hope someone can help me, and i would really appruciate it.

```
foreach( $results as $result )
  { 

         echo $result->prams->product_name;
 }
```

Error that shows when this code gets executed:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

I really would need some advice on this.

Thank you!

Comment: its because `params` isn't an object, its a string of JSON data, you need to decode it before you can access it's data based on key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every item in your list is an object:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
[1] => stdClass Object
```

And every object has a `params` property which is a string containing JSON data.

You need to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) built-in function to convert JSON string to an object or array.

Try this approach:

```
$paramsDecoded = json_decode($result->params, true);
print $paramsDecoded['product_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thanks to all who helped,

I managed to make it functional.

So im gonna post here all the code for everyone else that passes on the same waters and needs help.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('params')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__modules'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('module') . ' = '. $db->quote('mod_products') .' AND '. $db->quoteName('language') . ' <> '. $db->quote('en-GB'));

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

$count = count($results);
```

What i did to make the functionality i needed:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
    $json = $results[$i]->params;
    $product = json_decode($json);

    // code here, example
    echo $product->product_subtitle;

}
```

So, yes. I needed to decode using json_decode first, before using it on other parts of the code.

Thanks for helping. Hope this posts helps other developers who same as me, will have difficulties working with the way Joomla manipulates objects stored in database.